# Is possible to decompiled jar is to recompile it

Tags: java

I have a JAR file. I want to decompile it and resolve the bugs and then recompile it. Is it possible? And how?

I have a spring boot project l make. It has a JAR. I want to decompile the JAR, resolve the bug and then need recompile it.

Comment: Possible, yes. Probable, no.

Comment: We cannot tell you whether it will work.  It depends on the application, how the JAR file was created, the bug you are trying to fix ... and your ingenuity.  On problem is that decompilers often don't produce correct Java code that is functionality equivalent to the bytecodes.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is obtain the original source code.

However, if that's not possible, the following is how you can archive source:

1. Run `mvn dependency:get \ -DrepoUrl=https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/ \ -Dartifact=com.jetbrains.intellij.java:java-decompiler-engine:LATEST \ -Ddest=.` in your terminal. This will download JetBrains' decompiler (also known as [fernflower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler)).
2. Run it: `java -jar java-decompiler-engine -dgs=1 -ind=4 your-spring-project.jar your-spring-project-decompiled.jar`. `-dgs=1` is recommended because it includes generic signature (you don't need care if your project does not use them). `-ind=4` is also recommended because it will emit **3 spaces** per indentation on default configuration.
3. You will get source code in `your-spring-project-decompiled.jar`. You need to extract them as if it was ZIP archive (you don't have to rename them) to access decompiled source code.

Comment: The question is (in short) will this work for the OP's bug.  And that is unanswerable.